# Cannot properly configure Django to run tests with nosetests

Tags: python, django

I am having problems running `nosetests` from the system command line.

I installed `django-nose` and added it to `settings.py`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_nose',
]

TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
```

Next, I've created `.env` file with the following contents:

```sh
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

`settings.py` is in `mysite`, while `.env` is in `.`. Structure looks like this:

```
/hay
/mysite
/tests
.env
manage.py
```

Now, when I try to run `nosetests` while being in `.`, I am getting an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I don't know what more to do with this. I thought that `.env` file will sort this thing out.

-- edit

Running `nosetests` via the Django shell isn't possible, as it doesn't recognize the command.

Comment: It sounds like you're in the process in adding unittests to your codebase (as opposed to inheriting a huge codebase that already contains tests). Development on nosetests has been dormant for years now. Why not use pytest?

Comment: I am totally new to testing in Python in general. So far I've written tests for my services and models using `django.test.TestCase` and I've read that nose is the next step. If this is bad assumption, I would be grateful if you could point me to a better, more actual information :)

Comment: `pytest` and `pytest-django` are the next step ;-)

Comment: So I should discard `nose` and `django-nose` in favor of `pytest`, or work with both?

Comment: Just skip `nose` altogether.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to use `pytest` with Django ;)